# 2008 only DCs: is File Replication still necessary/required?

Tags: active-directory, file-replication-services

We're attempting a swing migration in our lab that's setup with two DCs:

OriginalDC: 2008 R2 DC (single forest, single domain) at 2008 functional level.

TempDC: has been promoted to a global catalog DC; running 2008 R2 as well.

The swing documentation explicitly states that event ID 13516 must exist for the dcpromo of TempDC to be considered successful and to proceed with the documentation.  However, `repladmin /showrepl` only has `success` entries and SYSVOL shares are all present, dsa.msc shows all the users and objects, etc. of the OriginalDC.

Further to this, the File Replication services is disabled and enabling it throws errors.  Combing through the event log, I've found multiple references that seem to indicate that File Replication is no longer necessary and is deprecated in favor of Distributed File Services (DFS) replication.

We're working with support right now, but I'd like to hear from the SF community AD gurus on this.

Thanks

Comment: I've only migrated from W2K3 (to W2K8) using W2K3 TempDC's. I haven't done a W2K8R2 to W2K8R2 migration. Are you using a kit from SBSMigration.com? If so, is it a W2K8 to W2K8 kit (or R2 kit)? If so, does it not have updated instructions for DFSR?

Comment: @joeqwerty: we're going from 2008 Standard to 2011 SBS, but since there's no kit completed for that, we're working off of a modified/annotated kit that they've created for us.  The key here is that there's never been another domain/functional level outside of 2008; they were on a P2P network prior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need either one or the other, FRS or DRS - whichever one is actively replicating SYSVOL.

Which one is in use is the important thing; if your domain was originally created on 2008 or higher (with a 2008 or higher functional level), then it's using DFS by default and FRS can be safely ignored.

However, if it was created earlier, then FRS is used for SYSVOL replication, and having it down is a bad, bad thing.  To move an FRS-replicated SYSVOL over to DFS is an ugly process; see [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2008/02/08/sysvol-migration-series-part-1-introduction-to-the-sysvol-migration-process.aspx).